# Relaying RTMP stream from one server to another

Tags: stream, rtmp

There is a WWW page with Flash stream on it. I want to download and forward this stream to another streaming server, when possible - replace audio stream (e.g. translate), but **without** recompressing video stream. Usual way for this ATM is to capture and broadcast Flash player view from the web page, which is obviously suboptimal because video needs to be recompressed, making the quality notably worse and loading the cpu.

Has someone an idea how to do it? VLC seems to be able making relay, but it also seems not to support RTMP at all.

Comment: I put an answer at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869190/is-it-possible-to-pull-a-rtmp-stream-from-one-server-and-broadcast-it-to-another/11978820#11978820

Answer (score 0):

if you're ready to do this programmatically you can use [crtmpserver](http://www.rtmpd.com/) (C++) or [red5](http://www.red5.org/) (Java) with any RTMP client, otherwise this question doesn't belong to SO

Comment: If not - where does it belong to? 
Can red5 get a stream from one server and upload it to another? Is there a working solutinion for it?

Comment: @asdf: I don't know, maybe superuser.com?

Comment: Can someone answer it nevertheless?