# Is it possible to pull a RTMP stream from one server and broadcast it to another?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I essentially have a situation where I need to pull a stream from one Wowza media server and publish it to a Red5 or Flash Media Server instance with FFMPEG. Is there a command to do this? I'm essentially looking for something like this:

```
while [ true ]; do 
    ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:2000/vod/streamName.flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/streamName
done
```

Is this currently possible from FFMPEG? I remembered reading something like this, but I can't remember how exactly to do it.

Comment: Please update if you got the answer for it...Please

Comment: It's tricky because command will run only when stream is available. On interruptions it will end. For a reliable setup you can setup a Wowza live stream repeater https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-configure-a-live-stream-repeater or if you need fronted users to do setup re-streaming, can be done with a setup like https://broadcastlivevideo.com/publish-ip-camera-stream-to-website/ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. An example (pulling from a local server, publishing to a local server):

```
 $ ffmpeg -analyzeduration 0 -i "rtmp://localhost/live/b live=1" -f flv rtmp://localhost:1936/live/c
```

analyzeduration is to make it start faster.  You can also add other parameters in there to "reencode" etc. if desired.

Answer (score -1):

try typing in this way:

`$ffmpeg -i "[InputSourceAddress]" -f [Outputfileformat] "[OutputSourceAddress]"`

The input source address can be in type rtmp, or rtsp/m3u8/etc.