# Use FFMPEG to restream RTMP source to YouTube - no video stream in output

Tags: nginx, video, ffmpeg, youtube, rtmp

I am attempting to grab the .m3u8 file from an nginx-rtmp server and pass it along to YouTube rtmp. I believe this to be possible (for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11978820/1552594 although this is on the same host). The command I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 0 -i \
http://source.rtmp.server/hls/stream.m3u8 -pix_fmt yuv420p \ 
-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

However the output contains only audio and YouTube doesn't like it. The command produces following:

[image: NOOO VIDEOOOO]

As you can see no Video stream in output metadata, stream mapping shows only audio and the trace shows 0kb of Video for 651kb of Audio

Any help much appreciated

#### MORE INFO

Improved version of the command lifted from this article:

https://judge2020.com/restreaming-a-m3u8-hls-stream-to-youtube-using-ffmpeg/

"Restreaming a m3u8 HLS stream to Youtube using FFMPEG" AKA exactly what I am trying to do.

The command I am sending is now:

```
ffmpeg -re -i "http://source.rtmp.server/hls/stream.m3u8" \ 
-strict -2 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -flags \ 
+global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 3000k -f flv \ 
"rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

I got pretty much exactly the same response except with the Audio being read and output using `aac` codec.

[image]

#### MORE MORE INFO

I have found that adding a mapping can force the video stream into the output:

```
ffmpeg -re -i "http://source.rtmp.server/hls/stream.m3u8" \
-strict -2 -c:v copy -c:a -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 \ 
-flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 1000k \
-f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

This throws up the error that has presumably been resulting in the video stream being silently dropped:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Finally worked it out. The last issue above was a red herring and was due to missing a codec argument for the audio `-c:a`.

The complete working command is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -probesize 100M -analyzeduration 20M -re \ 
-i "http://source.rtmp.server/hls/stream.m3u8" -strict -2 -c:v \ 
libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -ar 44100 \ 
-ab 128k -ac 2 -b:v 2567k -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc \ 
-bufsize 1000k -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

The important parts are `-probesize` and `-analyeduration` - these need tweaking until they work. The `-re` flag is important to indicate restreaming. The various video codec declarations are also important - `-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p` or it will throw errors about the output size being 0x0. Finally the map flags ensure that both streams are included in the output: `-map 0:0 -map 0:1`

Comment: Hi, i am trying to send my own rtmp server data to youtube its not woking

$ffmpeg -i rtmp://{url}/live/ -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key